# SqlCompare command line remote server

Tags: redgate, sqlcompare

I am trying to use the sqlcompare command line utility to compare a local database and a remote database but I am having difficulty doing this.

I would like to specify a connection string or some way to connect to the remote server (Destination)

Here is the command I have so far:

```
sqlcompare /Database1:RootDev /Database2:RootProd /scriptFile:"_build\changes.sql" /f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want something along the lines below, using the switches /Server1 and /Server 2 to specify the servers.

```
sqlcompare /Server1:local\SQL2008 /Database1:RootDev /Server2:remote\SQL2008 /Database2:RootProd /scriptFile:"_build\changes.sql"
```

Full details on the [docs](http://documentation.red-gate.com/display/SC10/Switches+used+in+the+command+line#Switchesusedinthecommandline-/Server1:%3Cservername%3E)